# Android SDK Manager failed to create directory

Tags: 16.04, android

I am trying to install android SDK for the first time in Ubuntu 16.04. I've configured the path variables and I'm able to launch Android SDK Manager from terminal. However, when I'm installing packages from inside the manager, I get the error as follows

[image]

I'm thinking it's some issue related to permissions and all but I'm not able to resolve this. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a permission related issue only. Got it installing the packages by using `sudo` and providing the full path to `android` as `/path/to/sdk/rootfolder/tools/android`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to give permission for `studio.sh`

```
sudo chmod 777 studio.sh
```